# Add Different Range to Same Series in Chart

Tags: excel, vba, charts

Error " Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignments"

Please Help!!

```
ch.SeriesCollection(1).XValues=sh.Range(Cells(38, 10), Cells(39, 10) &","& Cells(49,10),Cells(50,10))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you were going for.

```vb
    ch.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = sh.Range( _
                                        sh.Range(sh.Cells(38, 10), sh.Cells(39, 10)).Address & _
                                        "," & _
                                        sh.Range(sh.Cells(49, 10), sh.Cells(50, 10)).Address _
                                     )
```

But its much better to be written like:

```vb
    ch.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Union( _
                                        sh.Range(sh.Cells(38, 10), sh.Cells(39, 10)), _
                                        sh.Range(sh.Cells(49, 10), sh.Cells(50, 10)) _
                                     )
```